# How to get rid of command feedback in minecraft ps4 1.16

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Its a simple question I've tried /commandfeedback false

Answer (score 1):

```
/gamerule sendcommandfeedback false
```

Answer (score -3):

Try "/commandblockoutput false"

Comment: This isn’t a command, next time maybe make sure your answer works. It’s okay to have a wrong answer but this command doesn’t even exist, maybe next time do a quick google search to make sure this command exists.